# Extract Strings from Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
from pandas import DataFrame,Series
import pandas as pd
df
text                                                 region
The Five College Region                           The Five College Region
South Hadley (Mount Holyoke College)              South Hadley
Waltham (Bentley University), (Brandeis Univer..) Waltham
```

The region should extract from `text`. 
If the row contains "(",remove anything after "(",and then remove the white space.
If the row doesn't contain "(", keep it and copy to the region.
I know I can deal it with `str.extract` function. But I'm troubled in writing right regex pattern

```
df['Region']  =df['text'].str.extract(r'(.+)\(.*')
```

This regex pattern can not extract first string
I also acknowledge that using split functon works for this problem

```
str.split('(')[0]
```

But I don't know how to put the result in a column.
Hope to receive answers covering both methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***option 1***
`assign` + `str.split`

```
df.text.str.split('\s*\(').str[0]

0    The Five College Region
1               South Hadley
2                    Waltham
Name: text, dtype: object
```

---

```
df.assign(region=df.text.str.split('\s*\(').str[0])

                                                text                   region
0                            The Five College Region  The Five College Region
1               South Hadley (Mount Holyoke College)             South Hadley
2  Waltham (Bentley University), (Brandeis Univer..)                  Waltham
```

***option 2***
`join` + `str.extract`

```
df.text.str.extract('(?P<region>[^\(]+)\s*\(*', expand=False)

0    The Five College Region
1               South Hadley
2                    Waltham
Name: text, dtype: object
```

---

```
df.join(df.text.str.extract('(?P<region>[^\(]+)\s*\(*', expand=False))

                                                text                   region
0                            The Five College Region  The Five College Region
1               South Hadley (Mount Holyoke College)             South Hadley
2  Waltham (Bentley University), (Brandeis Univer..)                  Waltham
```

Comment: Could you please help explain the regex pattern    "(?P<region>[^\(]+)\s*\(*"    ? I'm confused about it.

Comment: @DingruiZhang `?P<region>` is convention to name the extracted component.  This translates into the name of the extracted `pd.Series`.  `[^(]+` is one or more characters that are **not** `(`.  `\s*(*` is zero or more spaces followed by zero or more `(`.